# JSON get random flickr photo from userstream (flickr api)

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr

I have gotten the below to work. I would like to instead **display a random photo from a user's stream** - not per tag, and not via public; one specific user or photostream.

---

I would like to customize the below to pull in random photos from a specific user's feed; as opposed to it's current state, which is pooling in based on tags of all public photos.

```
$.getJSON("https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
               {
                  tags: "landscape", // I would like to filter just via user not tag
                  format: "json"
                },

                //The callback function
                function(data) {

                  //Get random photo from the api's items array
                    var randomPhoto = data.items[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.items.length)];  

                    $(".img-src").css({

                      position: "relative",
                      height: "100vh",
                    //Use the randomPhoto's link
                      backgroundImage: "url("+randomPhoto.media.m+")",
                      backgroundPosition: "center",
                      backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
                      backgroundSize: "cover"
                    });
                 }
             );
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I would like to customize JSON request above to not pull via all public flickr photos via tag - but only pull from a specific one users stream.

Comment: So that would be documented in the flickr api developer docs